# Does NReco.PDFgenerator supports accessibility?

Tags: vb.net, wkhtmltopdf, nreco

We use NReco.PDFGenerator in our application and the pdfs generated do not appear to be accessible. Is there any library that we can use or any other way to make these PDFs accessible?